# What does "pea's knees" mean?

Tags: idioms, expressions

What could an expression **pea's knees** mean in the following text?

> Can you see how he is loved in this place? Can you hear how these
>   fishy folk think that he is the pea's knees?
>
> (David Almond)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it should have been [*the bees’ knees*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-bee-s-knees).

Comment: It makes sense. The character in the book speaks "special English", he confuses letters in individual words so that he produces funny misspellings. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Given the "fishy folk", I wonder if it's a deliberate play on the fact that mushy peas is a traditional accompaniment to fish and chips in Britain, particularly North England, where Almond is from and sets at least some of his works.